In LaTex mode, check if we are not in math mode for aas package
I am using the aas package (auto-activating snippets). When I want a snippet to expand we can do so by putting the following in the use-package declaration in the .emacs file:
:cond #'texmathp
"infty"   "\\infty"

This only expands "infty" to "\infty" if we are in math mode. My question is how to expand a snippet if we are not in mathmode?
I tried things like ":cond !#'texmathp"  or "cond not #'texmathp" but I can not figure out how to negate the condition.
(I want "infty" to expand to "$\infty$" if we are not in mathmode, but "infty" to expand to "\infty" if we are in mathmode).

I have not looked further into the problem, but I guess you can simply define a function (defun nottexmathp () (not (texmathp))) and use it as condition :cond #'nottexmathp.

That worked thanks for taking time to write that!  However, I should have realized I would not be allowed to make two different snippets both with the key "infty".

As dalanicolai noted, I can just make a function (defun nottexmathp () (not (texmathp))) then use :cond #'nottexmathp
I used dalanicolai's provided code as a start to a new package that auto-expands snippets. The aas package kept ignoring some of my defined snippets, which I am not sure why. So here is my package (which still uses yas for more complex snippets which require marks $0, $1, etc):
;;; Package -- Summary Commentary: Better Auto Expansion (of snippets)
;;; Just uses hash table. Creates an alist of "char" to "keys that end
;;; with char". That way when you press 'y' it looks at all keys that
;;; end in y to see if what has been typed should be replaced. So if
;;; you want to replace "infty" with "$\infty$" once you type 'i' it
;;; looks for keys that end in 'i'. Type 'n' and it looks for keys
;;; that end with 'n'. Once you get to the 'y' it finds "infty" in the
;;; hash table and replaces "infty" with "$\infty$".
;;; 
;;; Contains two lists: only-text-mode-list and math-mode-list. If
;;; they share a key then the value that replaces the key comes from
;;; math-mode-list if you are in mathmode (according to the function
;;; texmathp) and if you are not in mathmode then key is replaced with
;;; value from only-text-mode-list.
;;; 
;;; Code:

;; for the complex values which contain $0, $1, etc
(require 'yasnippet) 
(yas-global-mode 1)

;; texmathp is required; I think it is provided in auctex package.

(setq only-text-mode-list '(
("cembedfunctions" . "$\\rho_{-}, \\rho_{+}:[0,\\infty) \\to [0,\\infty)$ ")
("align"           . "\n\\begin{align*}\n $1 \n\\end{align*}\n")
("mk"              . "$$1$$0")
("HH"              . "$\\mathcal{H}$")
("TT"              . "$T$")
("FF"              . "$\\mathbb{F}$")
("C*a"             . "$C^*$-algebra")
("k-graph"         . "$k$-graph")
("k-theory"        . "$K$-theory")
("C*-identity"     . "$C^\\ast\\text{-identity}$")
("roealgebra"      . "$C^*_{u}$")
("cg0"             . "$c > 0$$0")
("kg0"             . "$k > 0$$0")
("Cg0"             . "$C > 0$$0")
("Kg0"             . "$K > 0$$0")
("dg0"             . "$\\delta > 0$$0")
("eg0"             . "$\\epsilon > 0$$0")
("rg0"             . "$R > 0$$0")
("sg0"             . "$S > 0$$0")
("yiny"            . "$y \\in Y$$0")
("xinx"            . "$x \\in X$$0")
("xyinx"           . "$x,y \\in X$$0")
("BB"              . "$B$$0")
("YY"              . "$Y$$0")
("yy"              . "$y$$0")
("xx"              . "$x$$0")
("zz"              . "$z$$0")
("ZZ"              . "$\\mathbb{Z}$$0")
("AA"              . "$A$$0")
("XX"              . "$X$$0")
("dm"              . "\n\\[\n $1 \n\\]$0")
)
)

;; Ifin math mode, replace the key with the value. If not in math mode
;; either leave the key unchanged or replace the key with the value in
;; only-text-mode-list if the key is in only-text-mode-list.
(setq math-mode-list '(
("binom" . "\\binom{${1:n}}{${2:k}}")
("omax"     . "\\otimes_{\\max}")
("rho"      . "\\rho")
("odt"      . "\\odot")
("odot"     . "\\odot")
("max"      . "\\max")
("min"      . "\\min")
("otimes"   . "\\otimes")
("forall"   . "\\forall")
("perp"     . "\\perp")
("x0"       . "x_{0}")
("x1"       . "x_{1}")
("y0"       . "y_{0}")
("y1"       . "y_{1}")
("vphi"     . "\\varphi")
("ell"      . "\\ell")
("leq"      . "\\leq")
("geq"      . "\\geq")
("ox"       . "\\otimes")
("o+"       . "\\oplus")
("span"     . "\\text{span}")
("pi"       . "\\pi")
("nimplies" . "\\centernot\\implies")
("implies"  . "\\implies")
("rangle"   . "\\rangle")
("ip"       . "\\langle( $1 \\rangle)$0")
("paren"    . "\\left( $1 \\right)$0")
("pmat"     . "\\begin{pmatrix}\n$0\n\\end{pmatrix}")
("bmat"     . "\\begin{bmatrix}\n$0\n\\end{bmatrix}")
("Bmat"     . "\\begin{Bmatrix}\n$0\n\\end{Bmatrix}")
("vmat"     . "\\begin{vmatrix}\n$0\n\\end{vmatrix}")
("Vmat"     . "\\begin{Vmatrix}\n$0\n\\end{Vmatrix}")
("matrix"   . "\\begin{matrix}\n$0\n\\end{matrix}")
("pmat"     . "\\begin{pmatrix}$0\\end{pmatrix}")
("vmat"     . "\\begin{vmatrix}$0\\end{vmatrix}")
("Vmat"     . "\\begin{Vmatrix}$0\\end{Vmatrix}")
("matrix"   . "\\begin{matrix}$0\\end{matrix}")
("ol"       .  "\\overline{$1}$0")
("TT"       . "\\mathcal{T}")
("bxy"      . "\\mathcal{B}(X,Y)")
("FF"       . "\\mathbb{F}")
("bofh"     . "\\mathcal{B}(\\mathcal{H})")
(" o "      . " \\circ ")
("#"        . "\\#")
("cal"      . "\\mathcal{$1}$0")
("langle"   . "\\langle")
("symdif"   . "{$2}~\\Delta~{$1}$0")
("xinx"     . "x \\in X$0")
("0inf"     . "[0, \\infty)$0")
("#"        . "\\#$0")
("diam"     . "\\text{diam}$0")
("ms"       . "\\mathscr{$1} $0")
("asdim"    . "\\text{asdim } $0")
(" in "     . " \\in $0")
("maps"     . "\\mapsto")
("to "      . " \\to $0")
("nrm"      . "\\left\\| $1 \\right\\|$0")
("dist"     . "\\text{dist}_{$1} $0")
("cnrm"     . "\\|\\cdot\\|")
("sm"       . "\\setminus")
("beg"      . "\\begin{$1}\n$0\n\\end{$1}")
("@v"       . "\\varphi")
("@p"       . "\\phi")
("@a"       . "\\alpha")
("@b"       . "\\beta")
("@g"       . "\\gamma")
("@G"       . "\\Gamma")
("@d"       . "\\delta")
("@D"       . "\\Delta")
("@e"       . "\\epsilon")
(":e"       . "\\varepsilon")
("@z"       . "\\zeta")
("@t"       . "\\theta")
("@T"       . "\\Theta")
(":t"       . "\\vartheta")
("@i"       . "\\iota")
("@k"       . "\\kappa")
("@l"       . "\\lambda")
("@L"       . "\\Lambda")
("@s"       . "\\sigma")
("@S"       . "\\Sigma")
("@u"       . "\\upsilon")
("@U"       . "\\Upsilon")
("@o"       . "\\omega")
("@O"       . "\\Omega")
("@m"       . "\\mu")
("@n"       . "\\nu")
("text"     . "\\text{$1}$0")
("txt"      . "\\text{$1}$0")
("\""       . "\\text{$1}$0")
("sr"       . "^{2}")
("cb"       . "^{3}")
("rd"       . "^{$1}$0")
("_"        . "_{$1}$0")
("sts"      . "_\\text{$0}")
("sqc"      . "\\sqcup")
("Sq"       . "\\sqrt{ $1 }$0")
("//"       . "\\frac{$1}{$2}$0")
("ee"       . "e^{ $1 }$0")
("-1"       .  "^{-1}")
("conj"     . "^{*}")
("Re"       . "\\mathrm{Re}")
("Im"       . "\\mathrm{Im}")
("bf"       . "\\mathbf{$1}$0")
("bb"       . "\\mathbb{$1}$0")
("rm"       . "\\mathrm{$1}$0")
("trace"    . "\\mathrm{Tr}")
("hat"      . "\\hat{$1}$0")
("bar"      . "\\bar{$1}$0")
("dot"      . "\\dot{$1}$0")
("ddot"     . "\\ddot{$1}$0")
("cdot"     . "\\cdot")
("tilde"    . "\\tilde{$1}$0")
("und"      . "\\underline{$1}$0")
("vec"      . "\\vec{$1}$0")
("ann"      . "a_{n}")
("bnn"      . "b_{n}")
("cnn"      . "c_{n}")
("xnn"      . "x_{n}")
("xii"      . "x_{i}")
("xjj"      . "x_{j}")
("xp1"      . "x_{n+1}")
("ynn"      . "y_{n}")
("yii"      . "y_{i}")
("yjj"      . "y_{j}")
("ooo"      . "\\infty")
("sum"      . "\\sum")
("prod"     . "\\prod")
("\\sum"    . "\\sum_{$1=$2}^{$3} $0")
("\\prod"   . "\\prod_{$1=$2}^{$3} $0")
("lim"      . "\\lim_{ $1 \\to $2 } $0")
("xx"       . "\\times")
("**"       . "\\cdot")
("==="      . "\\equiv")
(" neq "    . "\\neq $0")
(">="       . "\\geq")
("<="       . "\\leq")
(">>"       . "\\gg")
("<<"       . "\\ll")
("simm"     . "\\sim")
("sim="     . "\\simeq")
("prop"     . "\\propto")
("<->"      . "\\leftrightarrow ")
("and"      . "\\cap")
("orr"      . "\\cup")
("notin"    . "\\not\\in")
("subs"     . "\\subset")
("sub="     . "\\subseteq")
("sup="     . "\\supseteq")
("eset"     . "\\emptyset")
("in"       . "\\in")
("rt"       . "\\rtimes")
("mxrt"     . "\\rtimes_{\\max}")
("mnrt"     . "\\rtimes_{\\min}")
("hkarr"    . "\\hookrightarrow")
("hookarr"  . "\\hookrightarrow")
("surj"     . "\\twoheadrightarrow")
("..."      . "\\ldots")
("set"      . "\\\\{ $1 \\\\}$0")
("LL"       . "\\mathcal{L}")
("HH"       . "\\mathcal{H}")
("UU"       . "\\mathcal{U}")
("cc"       . "\\mathbb{C}")
("RR"       . "\\mathbb{R}")
("ZZ"       . "\\mathbb{Z}")
("NN"       . "\\mathbb{N}")
("\\int"    . "\\int $1 \\, d$2 $0")
("cases"    . "\n\\begin{cases}\n$0\n\\end{cases}")
("amin"     .  "\\argmin_{$1}") ; 
)
)

(defun merge-alists (simple-alist math-alist)
  (let ((merged-alist '()))
    (dolist (pair simple-alist)
      (let ((key (car pair))
            (value (cdr pair)))
        (if (assoc key math-alist)
            (let ((value-math (cdr (assoc key math-alist))))
              (push (cons key `(if (texmathp) ,value-math ,value)) merged-alist))
          (push (cons key value) merged-alist))))
    (dolist (pair math-alist)
      (let ((key (car pair))
            (value (cdr pair)))
        (unless (assoc key simple-alist)
          (push (cons key `(if (texmathp) ,value ,key)) merged-alist))))
    (nreverse merged-alist)))

(setq my-merged-alist (merge-alists only-text-mode-list math-mode-list))

(defun create-new-alist (alist)
  "Create a new alist from ALIST based on the last character of the keys."
  (let ((new-alist '()))
    (dolist (pair alist)
      (let* ((key (car pair))
             (last-char (substring key -1))
             (existing-entry (assoc last-char new-alist)))
        (if existing-entry
            (setcdr existing-entry (append (cdr existing-entry) (list pair)))
          (setq new-alist (append new-alist (list (cons last-char (list pair))))))))
    new-alist)
)


(defun my-auto-expand ()
  (when-let (words (alist-get (char-to-string last-command-event)
                              my-autoexpand-alist nil nil #'string=))
    (while words
      (let* ((def (car words))
             (word (car def))
             (start (- (point) (length word)))
             (end (point)))
        (cond ((string= (buffer-substring-no-properties start end) word)
               (let ((new-pattern  (eval (cdr def))))
                 (undo-boundary) ;; allows "undo" to remove the auto-expand
                 (delete-region start end)
                 (yas-expand-snippet new-pattern start start))
               (setq words nil))
              (t (setq words (cdr words)))))))
)

(setq my-autoexpand-alist (create-new-alist my-merged-alist))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'my-auto-expand nil t)))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook   (lambda () (add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'my-auto-expand nil t)))

(provide 'init-bae)


I guess there must be some package that already implements the functionality you want. However, if it does not already exist, then you can write the functionality with only a little lisp yourself, it's fun to do.
For example, you can achieve the functionality you want by adding the following lines to your dotfile
(setq my-autoexpand-alist '(("a" ("aaa" . "bbb"))
                            ("y"
                             ("infty" . (if (texmathp) "\\infty" "$\\infty$"))
                             ("testy" . "testo"))))

(defun my-auto-expand ()
  (when-let (words (alist-get (char-to-string last-command-event)
                              my-autoexpand-alist nil nil #'string=))
    (while words
      (let* ((def (car words))
             (word (car def))
             (start (- (point) (length word)))
             (end (point)))
        (cond ((string= (buffer-substring-no-properties start end) word)
               (let ((new-pattern (eval (cdr def))))
                 (replace-string-in-region word new-pattern start end)
                 (forward-char (length new-pattern)))
               (setq words nil))
              (t (setq words (cdr words))))))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'my-auto-expand nil t)))

The function searches only for replacements in the list of conses corresponding with the key in the my-autoexpand-alist that matches the last letter typed.
I avoid the use of looking-back because its docstring recommends to avoid using it if possible.
You can use the above code in combination with the aas package. If you are adding many more definitions (replacements) then you could add functionality to make the function more efficient, but it is fine to use this version if your alist contains only a few replacement definitions.
The code can probably be refined/simplified, and other users are very welcome to suggest refinements (or some alternative package which already implements the desired functionality).

You're awesome for writing that out! But, it is not working for me and I am not sure why, any idea? It doesn't seem to do anything

Did you add the code above to your dotfile, and restart Emacs? Then, what is the value of the post-self-insert-hook while you are woking in some LaTeX buffer?
